# How do I automatically set the User-Agent of Firefox Developer Edition to be that of the latest stable version?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, user-agent

I want to make it so that Firefox Developer Edition will always report that it's the latest Firefox stable without having to manually set the User-Agent every time the stable version updates. Is there a way to do this automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You may set an `about:config` option in the `user.js` file in the
profile folder to force the User Agent.

The option concerned is `general.useragent.override`.

Try it with a line like this:

```
user_pref("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit/…")
```

You may also try an add-on such as
[User-Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher-revived/).

Reference :
[How can I specify a particular user-agent string in a command-line invocation of Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42093473/how-can-i-specify-a-particular-user-agent-string-in-a-command-line-invocation-of)